# Angular stop working after start reinit jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using this jquery lib: 
https://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

after I try to reinit script like in documentation angular stop working... Here is what I try to do.

```
$scope.$watch('vm.brand', function(newval, old) {
       console.log("test")
        if(newval === '333') {
           $("select").imagepicker();
        }
});
```

Anyone know how to slove this?

Comment: What do you mean by Angular stops working? Do you receive any errors? Does the view fail to update? Please be more specific.

Comment: It's always a pain in the ass when using angular and jquery at the same time. Is there any possibility to use any angularjs image picker?

Comment: Problem is when `vm.brand` change and this function is called: `$("select").imagepicker();` angular just stop working... Validation stop, ng-if, evrything...

Answer (score 0):

You make some mistakes : 
- A Controller must never know the view (your HTML)
- You try to access every select on your application (it's bad)

You should : 
- Use a directive and use the variable `element`

Comment: Problem is not with controller, problem is with jquery: `$("select").imagepicker();` that function stop angular